# Why doesn't float within a @media query work as expected?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**EDIT**: [Resolved!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155755/why-doesnt-float-within-a-media-query-work-as-expected/22156063#comment33628877_22155755)

---

**EDIT:** [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22156063/37772) resolves the issue; however, it's not clear to me *why* the `float` declaration within the `@media` query doesn't work.  Any thoughts would be appreciated--

---

I have two data sets which are semantically one, chronological list.  On tablets and browsers, I'd like to display these lists as two separate columns.  On a phone or smaller screens, I'd like to collapse the two columns into a single column *preserving their chronological order*.  A solution which preserves the chronological ordering of the elements is an ordered list which I style to create the appearance of two columns; *e.g.* [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vyMWS/) is a fiddle demonstrating that solution.

Basically, I have an ordered list whose list elements have one of two classes (`.left` or `.right`) which cause them to float to the left and right, and I have a set of `@media`-queries which creates the responsive behavior I want.  The issues is that while I can float them left and right, I don't know how to create the *vertical* flow I want.  *e.g.* in [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyMWS/), I have a list,

```html
<body>
    <ol>
        <li class='left'>Left 1 <br> Left 1 continued </li>
        <li class='right'>Right 1</li>
        <li class='right'>Right 2</li>
        <li class='left'>Left 2</li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

which is styled simply,

```html
<style>
    ol {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 50em) {
        body {
            width: 50em
        }
        li {
            width: 45%
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 50em) {
        li {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .left {
            float: left;
        }

        .right {
            float: right;
        }
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    li.left {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    li.right {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

But, with that, the content in the right column appears shifted down--as below:
[image: JSFiddle Screenshot]

instead of what I actually want, which would look something like this:
[image: What I wish the JSFiddle looked like]

I know that I can implement this as two separate columns/`div`s which are re-ordered by JavaScript on a smaller screen, but I was wondering if there was a way which would preserve the semantic aspect of their ordering while avoiding the vertical flow issues here?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this has been asked many times here, in one form or another, and the answer is always "sorry, not possible."

Comment: Happy to close it as a duplicate, but [Kevin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22156063/37772) seems functional; however, I'm not sure why the `float` in the `@media` query doesn't work.  Thoughts?

Comment: @aresnick Simple: If the width of your document is more than 50em, then your li elements should be floating. Which is what it does now. Before of this, your elements were floating only if the document width was less than 50em, and not only this. You also set li's width to 100% nullifying the effect of `float`. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyMWS/1/)

The problem is that those elements were not floating elements.
Giving them the `float` property in that particular media query simply doesn't work as you expected. Check now, it should go. Just enlarge the window of the fiddle.

Your new CSS

```
@media (max-width: 50em) {
    li {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


li.left {
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}

li.right {
    float:right;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is great; thanks!  Could you elaborate on why "Giving them the float property in that particular media query simply doesn't work as you expected?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is quite a bit of a different attemp. Maybe it fits your need.
http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/vyMWS/2/

your question is quite confusing, you should have not put the phrases left and right into your image, but: start story 1 + end story 1 etc.

```
ol
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -ms-column-count: 2;
    -o-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;

}

ol li
{
    background-color: blue;
     display: block;
}

ol li:nth-child(2n)
{
    background-color:red;
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
    ol
    {
       -webkit-column-count: 1;
      -moz-column-count: 1;
      -ms-column-count: 1;
      -o-column-count: 1;
      column-count: 1;  
    }
}
```